# Антоним к слову "аскетичный"?

Tags: антонимы

Какой антоним у прилагательного **"аскетичный"**?

Comment: Прихотливый, расточительный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аскетичный = Аскетический.

> АСКЕТИЧЕСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. Относящийся к аскетизму (1-2 зн.);
>   связанный с ним. Книги аскетического содержания. 2. Свойственный
>   аскету; такой, как у аскета. А-ое самоотречение. А-ая жизнь. А-ое
>   лицо. 3. Характеризующийся намеренной ограниченностью в использовании
>   изобразительных средств. А-ая гамма красок. <Аскетически, нареч.

Первые два значения бесспорных антонимов иметь скорее всего не могут. Первое - прилагательное относительное (они редко имеют достаточно точные антонимы), второе вообще едва ли не притяжательное. 
Впрочем, есть слово **"сибаритский"** - относящийся к *сибариту*, в каком-то смысле сибарит - антоним аскету. Правда аскетизм - это некая философия, а сибаритство - состояние... Так что антоним не точный. 
Да, **Гедонистический (гедонистский)** - из этого же ряда (спасибо Р. М.), не очень точно, но в чем-то подходит.

В некотором значении подойдет **"обильный", "пышный", "цветущий", "плодородный"** (и тому подобное), но это совсем уж узкое значение, не знаю, подойдет ли вам.

К третьему значению более всего подходит **"помпезный"**, но тоже не стопроцентно.

Answer (score 4):

*Пышный, сладострастный, фривольный, гедонистический* (стремящийся к удовольствиям, полный наслаждений), *невоздержанный, плотский, сибаритский, чувственный, мирской, экстравагантный, эпикурейский, жизнелюбивый, развратный, шикарный, разгульный, праздный, изнеженный...*

Comment: За "гедонистический" - плюс. Не вспомнил этого слова. Эпикурейцы - это уже далековато...

Comment: Эпикурейский - сибаритский, чувственный,  считающий высшим благом  наслаждение жизнью (в отсутствие физической боли и тревог).

Comment: Эпикуреи́зм — философское учение, исходящее из идей Эпикура и его последователей. Согласно ему, высшим благом считается наслаждение жизнью, которое подразумевает отсутствие физической боли и тревог, а также избавление от страха перед смертью и богами, представляющимися безразличными к происходящему в мире смертных. - ЧТО ЗДЕСЬ СИБАРИТСКОГО???

Comment: Эпикуреизм: 1.Учение древнегреческого философа-материалиста и атеиста Эпикура. 2. Мировоззрение, возникшее на почве искаженного истолкования этого учения как стремления к удовлетворению чувственных инстинктов и достижения личного блага. 3. перен. Склонность к чувственным удовольствиям, к изнеженной жизни. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/79468 Отсюда и синонимы: гурманство, жуирование, сибаритство, чувственность. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/107095/%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE

Answer (score 3):

У прилагательного аскетичный (аскетический) **три основные значения**, поэтому антонимы подбираются к каждому из этих значений:

**Аскетичный образ жизни**. Антонимы: Разгульный, веселый, невоздержанный, чувственный.

**Аскетичное лицо, внешность.** Антонимы: здоровый,  пышный, румяный, полнокровный, жизнерадостный, молодцеватый.

**Аскетичная живопись**: Антонимы: яркая, светлая, насыщенная.

Из словаря:

АСКЕТИЗМ,  1. **Жизненный принцип**, заключающийся в строгом воздержании, отказе от земных благ и удовольствий во имя достижения нравственного совершенства 2. **Образ жизни**, основанный на таком принципе. 3. Намеренная ограниченность в использовании изобразительных средств **в произведениях искусства.**

АСКЕТИЧЕСКИЙ,  1. Относящийся к аскетизму (1-2 зн.); связанный с ним. Книги аскетического содержания. 2. Свойственный аскету; такой, как у аскета. А-ое самоотречение. А-ая жизнь. А-ое лицо. 3. Характеризующийся намеренной ограниченностью в использовании изобразительных средств в произведениях искусства.

АСКЕТИЧНЫЙ, =Аскетический. А-ое лицо. А. образ жизни. Живопись художника  аскетична.

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. Автор не удосужился пониманием вопроса. К тому же само понимание "антонима" у автора "оставляет желать". Предлагая очень слабые антонимы (если их таковыми вообще можно назвать) к частным значениям вообще антонимов скорее всего  не имеющим, автор просто путается.